# Convert the unstructured string into specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following strings to convert into following specified format.

Given strings:

```
2019-07-06 8/7/2019 1:00:00 PMto2019-07-07 8/7/2019 4:00:00 AM
2019-07-06 8/7/2019 4:01:00 AMto2019-07-06 8/7/2019 10:00:00 PM
2019-07-06 1:00:00to2019-07-06 8/7/2019 4:00:00 AM
2019-07-06 8/7/2019 4:01:00 AMto2019-07-06 10:00:00 PM
```

For the above given string I want to convert into the following format:

Expected Result:

```
2019-07-06 13:00:00to2019-07-06 4:00:00
2019-07-06 4:01:00to2019-07-06 22:00:00 
2019-07-06 1:00:00to2019-07-06 4:00:00
2019-07-06 4:01:00to2019-07-06 22:00:00
```

My try:

```
DECLARE @D1 VARCHAR(MAX) = '2019-07-06 8/7/2019 4:01:00 AMto2019-07-07 8/7/2019 10:00:00 PM'

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@D1,CHARINDEX(' ',@D1)+1,CHARINDEX('M',@D1)-CHARINDEX(' ',@D1))) >= 19
       THEN REPLACE(@D1,SUBSTRING(@D1,CHARINDEX(' ',@D1)+1,CHARINDEX('t',@D1)-CHARINDEX(' ',@D1)-1),CAST(SUBSTRING(@D1,CHARINDEX(' ',@D1)+1,CHARINDEX('t',@D1)-CHARINDEX(' ',@D1)-1) AS TIME(0)))
       ELSE @D1
       END DateTime_result
```

Unable to get it for second occurrance of 8/7/2019.

Comment: SQL Server really isn't the best tool for these types on string manipulations, in my opinion. This seems more like the data needs to be fixed in the application, and then the data stored properly in your database, not as 1 value like `'2019-07-06 13:00:00to2019-07-06 4:00:00'` but as 2 `datetime(2)` columns; one for the start and one for the end dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script..

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(MAX) = '2019-07-06 8/7/2019 1:00:00 PMto2019-07-07 8/7/2019 4:00:00 AM'

select cast(CONVERT(DATETIME2,(replace(substring(@D,1,CHARINDEX('to',@D,1)-1),' 8/7/2019 ',' ')), 0) as varchar(22)) + ' to ' + cast(CONVERT(DATETIME2,(replace(substring(@D,CHARINDEX('to',@D,1)+2,len(@D)),' 8/7/2019 ',' ')), 0) as varchar(22))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(MAX) = '2019-07-06 8/7/2019 1:00:00 PMto2019-07-07 8/7/2019 4:00:00 AM'

select replace(@d,substring(@d,charindex('/',@D)-1,charindex('/',@D)-4),'')
```